# How to share feed into the Facebook using GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on Facebook app and wanted to add Share functionality so how I can do share functionality using Facebook graph API?

Comment: Try having a go at some code and then if you get stuck ask for help pasting what you have tried so far. http://developers.facebook.com should give you an idea of what you can do. You can probably accomplish what you want with the javascript sdk so look at that. People are more inclined to help if you show willing rather than just asking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

By the poor way, you can use the **Like Button** to the desired URL, but with the label "Recomend".

The better way is to develop the application with some Authorization to post inside the user's feed. By this way, you can use the **[Graph API](https://graph.facebook.com/)** to post inside user's feed.

If both ways are too time-expensive for you, try to use **[ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/)**.